# What people recite having their right-hand on their forehead after every fajr salat?

Tags: salat, dua

After every salat in masjid, I often see that some people recite something putting their right-hands on their head or forehead and counts in another hand.

What is that dua and where they have found it?

If it really exists, then what is the benefit of reciting it and how many times should it be recite?

Jajakallah.

Comment: This sounds very strange to me and has no real basis nor back up in the sunna of our Prophet (pbuh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they are reciting this dua:

"Ya Qawiyyu" about 3 times.

I think this because when i was doing my hifz my shaikh told me to do this because it will make my memory stronger.
This website might explain a little in more detail inshallah:
http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/19916

Answer (score 0):

Placing hand on[image]
 This is hadith is in abu daud that the prophet Muhammed s.a.w said 2 hazrat jabir r.a that after salam when namaz finishes read this dua and not to stop doing so through out his life after farz namaz

Comment: Can you share the exact Hadith?