# Does saying ya qawiyyu 11 times keeping right hand on the head after each fard prayer increase memory?

Tags: hadith, dua, authenticity

***Is it authentic according to Sahih Hadith?***
To say Ya Qawiyyu 11 times after every obligatory prayer while keeping the right hand on the back part of the head increases memory.

Comment: You are referring to this answer: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31074/what-people-recite-having-their-right-hand-on-their-forehead-after-every-fajr-sa/31370#31370. And: http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/19916

Comment: @NanoAdam JazaaKa Allaahu Khairan. I understood the matter from the link.